# Change color of text in WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building my first WP site and I have encountered a few minor issues.
I am running the "Minamaze" theme and I wan to change a few things:
1. Style of text
2. Color of text
3. Layout/type of text
I want to change the headings and the main body text.
It mainly concerns the [index page of my site](http://primcasino.se), but also my under pages for the future.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This ist not really a PHP question but more of a CSS/Basic HTML question. You should change the tags of your question, so users can find it. Besides that, try to get some basic understanding of HTML and CSS from some tutorials. You should easily be able to fix this on your own afterwards.

Comment: Please move your question here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SD. this question doesn't belong on that site either. This is a theme-related question, and doesn't really belong on any Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @rnevius, you are right. But I think, question is relate to a wordpress specific theme, there are more chances to get answer for such question from active wordpress developers.

Answer (score -1):

If you can write a bit of css you can just enter the whole CSS of your theme. Just go to the Point Design on the left side of your Wordpress Backend. There should be a point "Theme editor" or something similar. There go into the main.css or style.css or a name like this and change the font-size and font-family attributes. Hope it helps